# When to use these following sentences?

Tags: meaning, difference

1. If I didn't take too much exercise yesterday, I would not be feeling so much pain.
2. If I hadn't taken too much exercise yesterday, I would not be feeling so much pain.

What do they mean? how to use them?

Comment: "What do they literally mean": what do you mean by 'literally'? What don't you understand about them? Where do these sentences come from? Do you want to know the difference between the two or is there more you'd like to know?

Comment: We don't usually say "take exercise" in American English (I am not sure about British English) and it sounds very old-fashioned and foreign.  We would just use "exercise" as a verb.

Comment: #1 is invalid (or at least, seriously ***non-idiomatic***). We only use *If I **didn't** [do something]...* to refer to "unreal **current** circumstances", such as *If I didn't like you I wouldn't spend time with you* (where it's implicit that speaker *does* like addressee - ***at time of speaking***). For an "unreal **past**" reference, it's *If I **hadn't loved** you, I wouldn't have married you* (which could validly be said even if speaker ***no longer*** loves addressee).

Comment: @stangdon - normal for the UK. But then we are old-fashioned and foreign, aren't we? 'Take exercise, not tablets – that’s NICE advice' says Professor Mike Hurley, Clinical Director, ESCAPE-pain Programme, Orthopaedic Research UK (ORUK). Note: NICE is the (UK) National Institute for health and Care Excellence, which recommends physical activity to help reduce joint pain.

Comment: Exercise noun (HEALTHY ACTIVITY) physical activity that you do to make your body strong and healthy: Swimming is my favourite form of exercise. **You really should take more exercise**. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exercise)